# How to package a Windows c++ game?

Tags: c++, distribution

**When you buy a game at the store, and want to play it on your computer, you do the following:**

1. Run a setup.exe
2. Install on computer
3. End up with an exe on your desktop (separate from its source files, asset files, etc.)

**How do I format my program (created from Visual Studio) to be like that?**

The farthest I have toward this goal is how my folder is currently structured:
[image]

**If you do not know how to completely separate my .exe from my source and asset files, then do you know how to be able to put my source, header, and sfml DLL's into a folder like the following:**

[image]

**Or do you know how to just bundle everything into one executable package?**

Comment: If you're using CMake this could be a good thing to try https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2016/09/create-windows-installer-using-cmake.html

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Professional has a "Setup project" type of project that creates a Windows Installer (msi) setup program. For versions up to 2010, it was bundled, and for 2013, there is an [extension](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension/) which does this.

As it is bundled with Visual Studio, it has only the most basic features, but can make a complete installer that will install prerequisites, do custom actions, and allows for some basic customization of the GUI.

When testing it, I recommend you create a virtual machine with a pristine copy of each Windows version you want to target, save the image, and try the installer. When you're finished, revert to the pristine copy, and try again if necessary. I use Virtual Box, but any virtual machine software should work.

The reason behind this is that depending on the libraries you use, a pristine install may not have the necessary DLLs, and a mere file copy will not be sufficient for the user to play your game. The Setup project helps you create an installer which includes all the necessary prerequisites so the game can be safely distributed to end users.